# selecting table using subquery sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, dynamic, subquery

Note: This is for SQL Server 2008.

I have a table that contains a number of columns, two of which are relevant to this discussion: Object and TableID. Object is a readable name. TableID corresponds to the table associated with Object, albeit the associated tables all begin with the letter `T`, as in table T135 or table T143.

```
SchemaTable
Object    TableID   /* Object is type varchar, TableID is type int
Form1     135
Form2     143
Form3     321
```

I want to craft a SQL query which will select contents from these tables, based on the value of Object. Here's what I have so far (which doesn't work):

```
SELECT Col1, Col2
FROM (
    SELECT (T' + CAST(TableID AS VARCHAR))
    FROM SchemaTable
    WHERE Object = 'Form1'
)Tbl_T
WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL
```

Can I use a subquery to select the table in this manner? If not, what else do you suggest and how?

Thank you very much for any help.

**Edit**

It seems that my question or query is not clear. Let me try to fix that.

I could select, say, table T135 directly like this:

```
SELECT Col1, Col2
FROM T135
WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL
```

But what I want to do is select Table T135, based on the column `Object` in table `SchemaTable`.

You see? I don't want to select a subtable of values from table `SchemaTable`. I just want to grab the `TableID` (i.e. 135) and select content from said table (i.e. T135). There is no `TableID` column in table T135. `TableID` effectively corresponds to the name of the table. It's not used as a key or identity into other tables. I think that's where the confusion lies in understanding what I seek to accomplish.

I hope that is more clearer.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You must use dynamic query.

Comment: can you add your expected results?

Comment: Thank you, Hamlet. I think that will do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can use a subquery to select a table in this manner. here's another example :

```
select * from  
(select ndc,client_id,pkg_sz from ABC where pkg_sz=100) dist,  
(select ndc,client_id from XYZ where pkg_sz=500) trns  
where trns.client_id = dist.client_id  
and dist.ndc=trns.ndc;
```